# How to correctly call jsonnet with imports from Python

Tags: python, python-import, jsonnet

I'm using jsonnet to build json objects that will be used by Python code, calling jsonnet from Python using the [bindings](http://jsonnet.org/ref/bindings.html).  I want to set up my directory structure so that the jsonnet files are in a subdirectory or subdirectories relative to where the Python code is run, something like:

`foo.py
jsonnet/
jsonnet/bar.jsonnet
jsonnet/baz.libsonnet`

Running `foo.py` should then be able to use `_jsonnet.evaluate_snippet()` on strings read from files in `jsonnet/` that import other files from `jsonnet/`.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default importer uses paths relative to the file from which they are imported. In case of `evaluate_snippet` you need to pass the path manually. This way jsonnet knows where to look for imported files.

If your intention is to process the files you can use a custom importer. (Digression: jsonnet tries to avoid the need to preprocess the source files, so there is probably a better way or a missing feature in jsonnet.)

Below is the complete, working example on how to use custom importers in Python (adjusted to the directory structure provided):

```
import os
import unittest

import _jsonnet


#  Returns content if worked, None if file not found, or throws an exception
def try_path(dir, rel):
    if not rel:
        raise RuntimeError('Got invalid filename (empty string).')
    if rel[0] == '/':
        full_path = rel
    else:
        full_path = dir + rel
    if full_path[-1] == '/':
        raise RuntimeError('Attempted to import a directory')

    if not os.path.isfile(full_path):
        return full_path, None
    with open(full_path) as f:
        return full_path, f.read()


def import_callback(dir, rel):
    full_path, content = try_path(dir, rel)
    if content:
        return full_path, content
    raise RuntimeError('File not found')


class JsonnetTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.input_filename = os.path.join(
            "jsonnet",
            "bar.jsonnet",
        )
        self.expected_str = '{\n   "num": 42,\n   "str": "The answer to life ..."\n}\n'
        with open(self.input_filename, "r") as infile:
            self.input_snippet = infile.read()

    def test_evaluate_file(self):
        json_str = _jsonnet.evaluate_file(
            self.input_filename,
            import_callback=import_callback,
        )
        self.assertEqual(json_str, self.expected_str)

    def test_evaluate_snippet(self):
        json_str = _jsonnet.evaluate_snippet(
            "jsonnet/bar.jsonnet",
            self.input_snippet,
            import_callback=import_callback,
        )
        self.assertEqual(json_str, self.expected_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

*Note: it's a modified version of [an example from jsonnet repo](https://github.com/google/jsonnet/blob/master/python/_jsonnet_test.py).*

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully get why you would use `evaluate_snippet()` (maybe mask the actual filenames via loading them from python into strings + `evaluate_snippet("blah", str)` ? ), instead of `evaluate_file()` - in any case that structure should just work ok.

Example:

**jsonnet_test.py:**

```
import json:
import _jsonnet

jsonnet_file = "jsonnet/bar.jsonnet"
data = json.loads(_jsonnet.evaluate_file(jsonnet_file))
print("{str} => {num}".format(**data))
```

**jsonnet/bar.jsonnet**:

```
local baz = import "baz.libsonnet";
{
  str: "The answer to life ...",
  num: baz.mult(6, 7),
}
```

**jsonnet/baz.libsonnet**:

```
{
  mult(a, b):: (
    a * b
  ),
}
```

Output:

```
$ python jsonnet_test.py
The answer to life ... => 42
```

Comment: I need to modify the jsonnet code before I pass it to _jsonnet.